# Proof of Ito's Formula in Ioannis Karatzas, Steven E. Shreve

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

In the proof of Itos formula in 'Brownian motion and Stochastic calculus' by Ioannis Karatzas, Steven E. Shreve it says the following

[image]

where

[image]

while the lemma 1.5.9 says

[image]

where is the 48 coming from?

Comment: It is a typo which has been corrected in the second edition (1998) of the book

Comment: @hamms Can you please share what was the correction?

Comment: The $\sqrt{48K^4}$ should be $\sqrt{6K^4}$